# Create sequence of repeated numbers without a list format

Tags: list-manipulation

I have a list,

```
list={"A","B",{{{{{"C"}}}}}, D, E , F , G}
```

and I want to choose the 'C' (i.e. the first element in the sixth level of the third element in 'list'), which is

```
list[[3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]]
```

and this gives

```
C
```

My question is how can I change the five '1' into a shorter way (use 'i' or something).
I tried

```
list[[3, ConstantArray[1, 5]]]
```

I know this is probably wrong because the ConstantArray gives a list, but it gives

```
{{{{{"C"}}}}, {{{{"C"}}}}, {{{{"C"}}}}, {{{{"C"}}}}, {{{{"C"}}}}}
```

Why is that?
And how can I make it right?
And in general, how can we make a sequence of repeated numbers, like 1,1,1,1,1 not in a list format (without {})?

Thanks for help!

Comment: How about `First@Cases[list, "C", Infinity]`?

Comment: @march Yes, it works, thanks! But what the 'Infinity' is doing here, does it represent 'all levels'? (but I tried several number instead, which doesn't work, so I guess it has a different meaning?) And is '@' the same as '@@'? Sorry I'm just a beginner in Mathematica..

Comment: For the symbols, [see here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/25616/29734). The `Infinity` means to search on all levels (except level 0, I think). In general, `Cases[expr, patt, level]` means to search on all levels *down to* `level`. If you do `First@Cases[list, "C", 6]`, it returns `"C"`, but not if you put 5 in place of 6.

Comment: @march Thanks so much! I was just struggling with all those symbols

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
list[[3, Sequence @@ ConstantArray[1, 5]]]
```

> "C"

Answer (score 1):

Since V 13.1 there is a new variant of `Splice`:

```
list[[3, Splice[Table[1, 5], Part]]]
```

C

Since `Splice` expressions do not automatically flatten inside heads other than `List` we had to give `Part` as 2nd argument.